# How to make an object float bottom right of a different tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position an image bottom right of a parent div.

CSS idea taken from a different answer - which doesn't work (the calc(100% - 200px) used page height 100% not parent div height 100%, unless I explicitly set a height to it).

Now I did some JS that does what I want (see my own answer), question: Can I (and how) get the same result without JS?

(and this work neither in jsfiddle nor in cssdesk.com, so you have to copy paste it to your own html file and navigate to it ...)

```
<style>
    .container {
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: green;
    }

    img {
        height: 200px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 50px double steelblue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: right;
        clear: right;
    }

    .spacer {
        /* height: calc(100% - 200px); <--- this one sadly doesn't work */
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<div style="background-color: blue">header + other stuff</div>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="spacer" id="spacer"></div>
    <img id="img" />
    <p>
        Conceptualizing random endpoints in an access matrix 
        provides reach extensions enterprise wide. Respective 
        divisions historically insignificant, upscale trendlines 
        in a management inventory analysis survivability format.
    </p><p>
        Document-centric projections unfetter traditional 
        auditing practices rivaling central process management. 
        Advanced functionality, easy administration, proclaim 
        the hallmarks of unprecedented opportunity.
    </p><p>
        Iteration system-wide engenders economies of scale, 
        cross-media technology, presentation action items and 
        life cycle replication.
    </p><p>
        Enterprise engenderment accelerates initiative platforms, 
        reducing staffing components, integration of technical 
        accessibility, resulting in bottom line pluralisms, 
        benefit-wise. Incidental re-sizing staff requirements 
        through attrition can be accelerated by paradigm shifts 
        and focusing on core suitability and cross-training.
    </p><p>
        Marketing teams input produce cross purposing in view of 
        goal alignments due to knowledge paucity, necessitating 
        workflow education and orientation. Media sourcing as an 
        acquisition strategy is counterproductive in a internet 
        environment in virtual component methodology. Imaging 
        through ideals rather than real world branding, is a 
        perilous undertaking with negative results. Branding 
        strategies generating motion as activity without 
        reproducible results is a ultimately futile effort if 
        left in place.
    </p><p>
        Analysis of funding is inappropriate in this effort as 
        assets are repurposed in statements who existence owe 
        their identity to their obscurity. Obfuscation of 
        responsibility underlines these offerings, whose primary 
        function is to generate revenue and secondarily to shift 
        accountability downstream.
    </p><p>
        Syntactically valid structuring implementation, 
        enhancement based reporting, technology development, 
        proprietary incidentals administration are all areas of 
        content modularization engaging visibility deficits. 
        Cyberliability management procedures underlining 
        performance degradation vouchsafing interdepartmental 
        communication guideline infrastructure for evaluating 
        content management.
    </p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">other stuff + footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using JS relies on the container's height to be updated by the browser and uses that to reposition the image.

The yellow box should be width:0px and empty like above, here it is wider only to visualize, what actually happens and to show debug output of the JS.

```
<style>
    .spacer {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
<script>
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
    function (e) {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var spacer    = document.getElementById("spacer");
        var img       = document.getElementById("img");

        var c_container = window.getComputedStyle(container);
        var c_img       = window.getComputedStyle(img      );

        var prev_width = 0;

        setInterval(
            function() {
                if (!document.hidden) {
                    var w_container = parseInt(c_container.getPropertyValue("width"));

                    var h_img       = parseInt(c_img      .getPropertyValue("height"));
                    if (w_container > prev_width) {
                        var h_container = h_img;
                    } else {
                        var h_container = parseInt(c_container.getPropertyValue("height"));
                    }
                    prev_width = w_container;
                    var h_spacer    = h_container - h_img;

                    spacer.style.height = h_spacer;

                    spacer.innerHTML = ""
                        + "w_container: " + w_container + "</br>"
                        + "prev_width: " + prev_width + "</br>"
                        + "h_container: " + h_container + "</br>"
                        + "h_img: " + h_img+ "</br>"
                        + "h_spacer: " + h_spacer + "</br>"
                    ;
                }
            }, 100
        );
    }
    );
})();
</script>
```